# Linear Independence Proof using Rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polyhedra

I am attempting to prove that three axes of rotation are linearly independent and so form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. I assert that given the fact that rotations about each axis involve no rotation about the other axes proves that they are linearly independent and so form a set spanning $\mathbb{R}^3$.

With that being said, I am unfamiliar with linear independence in this context, so I am unsure as to whether this is a valid strategy.

$Thanks$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (pairwise) orthogonal set is always linearly independent: Assume $v_1, v_2, v_3$ pairwise orthogonal and wlog , orthonormal, and assume $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+ c_3v_3=0$. Then take, e.g., $v_3$ and use: $\langle v_3, c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3\rangle =0= c_3$. Do similar for $v_1,v_2$

Comment: I agree with what you have written, as it indeed does follow from the definition of linear independence. However, if I am given that rotation about each individual axis results in only rotation about that axis (the other axes are solely translated under the rotation), does this necessarily imply linear independence?

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis: I would say, informally, that if any two were dependent, then rotation of a plane about any axis would contain the other two axes, i.e., two axes, either XY, YZ, XZ would be coplanar, but let me see how to make it rigorous.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis: How about this: Fix an axis, say z axis, and rotate it about the  xy-axis. Now, both x,y are actually normal to the zy-plane, so x,y,z cannot be part of the same plane, i.e., no two of them can be coplanar, and they are clearly not collinear. Is that the type of argument you're looking for?

Comment: I changed $<u,v>=0$ to $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$.  Notice how much closer "$>$" is to "$=$" than it is to "$v$". That problem doesn't happen with "$\rangle$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Ok, thanks.

Comment: @Gary, I think that will work. I have to try and implement it now- It's a proof involving polyhedra. Thanks.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis: No problem, let me know if you have a follow-up question.